# Neatly Print Comments Through Python Reddit API

Tags: python, praw, reddit

I am trying to do some text analysis with Reddit comments. The script I have currently prints out the body and upvote count all comments on a given subreddit's "hot" posts with more than 5 upvotes:

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=ID,
                     client_secret=SECRET, password=PWORD,
                     user_agent=UAGENT, username=UNAME)

subreddit = reddit.subreddit('cryptocurrency')

for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=10):
    submission.comments.replace_more(limit=10)
    for comment in submission.comments.list():
        submission.comment_sort = 'top'
        if comment.ups > 5:
            print(comment.body, comment.ups)
```

However, the outputs look something like this:

```
(u'Just hodl and let the plebs lose money on scamcoin ICO\'s that don\'t even have a working product. I don\'t understand some of these "traders" and "investors".', 9)
(u"Good idea imho but it's gonna be abused af. Think about it. It will be the sexual go to app real soon. If they will 'ban' nudity on it, then you will simply get the instagram chicks on there with all the horny guys liking their photos and giving them free money. 'if this gets 1000 likes I will post a pic of me in bikini' ", 7)
(u"But but but, I just sold a kidney and bought in at the top, now I can't afford to get the stitches removed!\n\n/s just in case.", 7)
```

Two questions:

1. Is there any way to convert the outputs to JSON using python?
2. If not, how can I get rid of all of the excess characters other than the body and the upvote count?

My ultimate goal is to have this output neatly organized so that I can analyze keywords vs. upvote count (what keywords get the most upvotes, etc).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 2: It looks like you are writing in Python 2, but are using Python 3 `print` syntax. To get rid of the tuple notation in your `print` call you need

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

at the top of your program.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is there any way to convert the outputs to JSON using python?

It's almost as simple as this

```
output_string = json.dumps(comments)
```

Except a couple of keys cause the error `TypeError: Object of type Foo is not JSON serializable`

We can solve this. PRAW objects which are not serializable will work correctly when converted to a string.

```
def is_serializable(k, v):
    try:
        json.dumps({k: v})
    except TypeError:
        return False

    return True

for comment in comments:
    for k, v in comment.items():
        if is_serializable(k, v):
            comment[k] = v
        else:
            comment[k] = str(v)
```

Now saving works.

```
json.dumps(comments)
```

> 2) If not, how can I get rid of all of the excess characters other than the body and the upvote count?

I think you're asking how to remove keys you do not want. You can use:

```
save_keys = ['body', 'ups']
for k in list(comment):
    if not k in save_keys:
        del comment[k]
```

We use `list(dict)` to iterate over a *copy* of `dict`'s keys. This prevents you from mutating the same thing you are iterating on.

`list(dict)` is the same as `list(dict.keys())